# Abelianization of general linear group over ring of integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

The question originally asked was, what will be the abelianization of $GL_n(F)$ provided that $F$ is a field? The answer is $F-\{0\}$ if $n \neq 2$ by proving that $SL_n(F)$ is the commutator subgroup . For $n =2$ we have $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But my question is what happens if we replace $F$ by integers $\mathbb{Z}$?

Because even if the commutator subgroup is contained in $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ the converse may not be true, since I do not have multiplicative inverse of every element. I will be thankful for any suggestions or help provided.

Comment: I see, please pardon me for posting such a well-known question, I was merely curious. Thank you.